# Excel/Google sheets: formula to "fill in the gaps"

Tags: excel, google-sheets

What's the best way to fill in the gaps in a spreadsheet column that looks like this?

[image: Gaps]

So that each row would be an accurately-divided step between the first and last value in the column? I don't want to have to manually add and divide each step.

**Edit**

The results I'm after would divide the difference by 18 because there are 18 cells between the top and bottom value, and insert the difference into each cell.

i.e.: the second cell in the screenshot would have the formula:

```
= 0.2151452046 + ((0.235 - 0.2151452046) / 18) (which equals 0.2361030442)
```

The third cell would then be:

```
= 0.2361030442 + ((0.235 - 0.2151452046) / 18)
```

Does that make sense? I don't know how better to explain it. Thanks.

**Second edit**

Here's the numbers with a manual formula that takes the previous value and adds the difference between the bottom and the top and divides it by the number of cells between:

[image: Updates]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select A1:A20 (e.g. the cell with 0.2151452046 to the cell with 0.235) and choose Home ► Editing ► Fill ► Series <kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Also accessed through <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>,<kbd>F</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

Comment: Well, you got me to go back and count through the cells again but that first example still comes out to A1:A20 in my head. Shouldn't have to specify anything if the cells are selected before the command is executed. Even the increment is calculated.